# Are the magnetic fields of a lightsaber canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

One widely held explanation of how lightsabers work is that they are a sword-shaped line of plasma confined by a strong magnetic field. Is this theory founded in anything from the Star Wars canon? And if so, where?

Comment: Can you please expand this question.  Try and [ask it to a rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) making sure you explain what it is you want to know to someone who just has the most basic information.  This way your question can be useful to people  coming to the site months and years from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Wookieepedia (Sourced well)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber)

> The typical lightsaber hilt consisted of a metal cylinder between
>   twenty and thirty-five centimeters in length. However, the size of
>   individuals hilts varied drastically, as the weapon was tailored to
>   the creator's specific needs and preferences. The lightsaber
>   mechanisms were contained within the hilt. High levels of energy
>   generated by a high-output Diatium power cell was unleashed through a
>   series of focusing lenses and energizers that converted the energy
>   into plasma. The plasma was projected through a set of focusing
>   crystals that lent the blade its properties and allowed for the
>   adjustment of blade length and power output. The ideal number of
>   crystals was three, though only one was required.
>
> Once focused by
>   the crystals, the plasma was sent through a series of field energizers
>   and modulation circuitry within the emitter matrix that further
>   focused it, making it into a coherent beam of energy that was
>   projected from the emitter. The blade typically extended about a
>   meter before being arced by the blade containment field back to a
>   negatively charged fissure ringing the emitter, where it was channeled
>   back to the power cell by a superconductor, completing the circuit.
>   Below is a list of the primary parts almost all lightsabers needed to
>   use to function properly:

Wookieepedia cites the follow books as reference:

[*Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345493346)

[*Luke Skywalker and the Shadows of Mindor*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345477456)

[*Outcast*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345509064)

Comment: What level of canon are these?

Comment: @Pureferret - Wookiepedia is not cannon.  The books it cites as a source would be EU Canon.  There are some source books for the RPG that are consistent with this though they are not canon either.

Comment: So does that make it T-canon? I lose track.

Comment: It makes it part of the extended universe canon, but not of necessity part of Lucas' canon.

Comment: @Pureferret - Books are typically S-canon, although individual facts in a specific book could be higher canon (if confirmed by a movie/TV show) or lower canon (if contradicted by same).

Comment: None of these sources are considered "canon" in the new regime

Comment: @Valorum Yeah this question predates Disney obliviating the hundreds of dollars I spend on the Legacy novels.