# What would happen if you disrupted the field of a Lightsaber

Tags: star-wars

In this question [What keeps lightsabers from going through each other?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21465/what-keeps-light-sabers-from-going-through-each-other/21471#21471) my answer discussed the fact that light-sabers are surrounded by an magnetic field. Today I was thinking, magnetic fields are not THAT hard to disrupt. What would happen if their was a breach in the containment field?

Would plasma spill out and consume to Jedi? Has this ever happened?

Comment: This was at least partially addressed in [Could a magnetic field disable a lightsaber?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/31743/2765)

Comment: Uncontrolled, unmodulated and unregulated fields aren't hard to disrupt, but a field designed to hold a stream of highly active and unstable plasma would certainly be the most regulated, controlled field ever. Capable of being struck by another such field and NEVER stop functioning no matter how many times it was struck by another. The fact is, we have NEVER seen a lightsaber fail to operate at anything other than peak efficiency. As a design engineer, no one would make a tool as dangerous without numerous failsafe protocols built in. When in doubt, it simply wouldn't ignite.